# How to define a variable if it is undefined in Vue.js 3 CLI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, wordpress-theming, vuejs3, vue-cli-3

I'm on my way to create a WordPress theme using Vue.js 3 CLI.
The main problem was WP database connection but I've, it seems to be, solved it.
Here is an “obvious” problem that I can not solve for 2 days. :)
Short about:

- There is a Vue environment inside the WP theme. This env. build the output js code, and my theme uses this code.

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "watch": "vue-cli-service build --watch --mode development"
  },
```

- In this way I connect the Vue.js script to my WP theme:

```
// theme-x engine chunk-vendors
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-mx-engine-chunk-vendors', get_template_directory_uri() . '/theme-x-engine/dist/js/chunk-vendors.js', [], _S_VERSION, true );
    
    wp_localize_script( 'theme-mx-engine-chunk-vendors', 'theme_mx_data', [

        'ajax_url'  => admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ),

        'post_type' => get_post_type(),
        'post_id'   => get_the_ID()

    ] );

    // theme-x engine app
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-mx-engine-app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/theme-x-engine/dist/js/app.js', ['theme-mx-engine-chunk-vendors'], _S_VERSION, true );
```

- In the code above you can see the variable “theme_mx_data”. It is my problem :) It’s working perfect when I refresh my WP website, but the console displays an error:

```
D:\OpenServer\domains\vue-mysql-wordpress.local\wp-content\themes\theme-mx\theme-x-engine\src\App.vue
  38:22  error  'theme_mx_data' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./src/main.js 6:0-28 7:10-13
 @ multi ./src/main.js
```

Yes, “typeof” ! :)
I tried a lot of different ways to define this variable if “theme_mx_data === undefined” but the console displays this error.
Here is some code:

```
set_mx_data() {

      let theme_data = {}

      if( typeof theme_mx_data !== "undefined" ) {

        theme_data = theme_mx_data

      }

      this.mx_data = theme_data

    }
```

Suggest me please, something.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when in a vue context I try to access a variable that vue doesn't know, I always put

```js
 window.MY_EXTERNAL_VARIABLE
```

so that he knows it's something outside of vue / the context

so in your case try with

```js
window.theme_mx_data
```